# ¿Como obtener el valor de una etiqueta dentro de un CarouselView en el código behind (Xamarin Forms)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarinforms

estoy explorando el mundo de xamarin y tengo la siguiente inquietud, estoy cargando un carousel de manera dinámica y necesito que al dar click en un ImageButton, pueda llevarme el valor de dicha etiqueta para el codigo behind y pasarsela a un método. Este es mi código xaml:

```
 <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Servicios}"
                      IndicatorView="indicatorView" HeightRequest="300">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Frame HasShadow="True"
                               BorderColor="DarkGray"
                               CornerRadius="5"
                               HeightRequest="200"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <StackLayout>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding CEM_Nombre}" 
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            FontSize="Large"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                        <ImageButton x:Name="btnImage"  ClassId="{Binding CEM_Id}" Source="{Binding CEM_Icono}" 
                                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                                            HeightRequest="150"
                                            WidthRequest="150"
                                         Clicked="Imagen_Clicked"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
```

Código behind:

```
  public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void Imagen_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //aqui necesito traer el valor que carge en el ImageButton

        }

    }
```

De antemano muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas!

Answer (score 0):

Deberias hacerlo por Command

```
 <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Servicios}"
                      IndicatorView="indicatorView" HeightRequest="300">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Frame HasShadow="True"
                               BorderColor="DarkGray"
                               CornerRadius="5"
                               HeightRequest="200"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <StackLayout>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding CEM_Nombre}" 
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            FontSize="Large"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                        <ImageButton x:Name="btnImage"  ClassId="{Binding CEM_Id}" Source="{Binding CEM_Icono}" 
                                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                                            HeightRequest="150"
                                            WidthRequest="150"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}
                                            Command={Binding MiComando}
                                         />
                                    </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>


public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public ICommand MiCommando;
    public HomePage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        MiCommando = new Command(ButtonClick);
    }
    private void ButtonClick(object sender)
    {
       var s= sender as Servicios; //Tu clase con la cual rellenas el Carousel.
    }

}
```